# Текст-кнопка в консоли на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать, чтобы в консоли определенный текст был другого цвета и на него можно было нажать (далее выполняется функция)

Comment: Кнопка в консоли? Никак.

Comment: @nomnoms12 где-то хихикает один ncurses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению это невозможно. Можно сделать реагирование консоли на определённые сочетания клавиш, либо на определённую команду. Для большего надо использовать GUI библиотеки